# Integrating PayPal Sandbox to Your Web Application

Tags: paypal, integration, paypal-sandbox

I have a web application and I want to integrate the PayPal Sandox to it.
What are the steps to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since PayPal's integration guides can be unclear for beginners and other online tutorials can be too long for a simple checkout implementation, this Q&A aims to integrate the PayPal Sandbox to your web application quickly and easily. **No external libraries or other downloads required.**

**STEP 1:** Create a PayPal Sandbox Account. Follow [this guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_create-accounts/) for test account creation.

**STEP 2:** Copy below sample HTML code for a basic ***Buy Now*** button (Single-Item Payment only):

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="payments@yourbusiness.com">

<!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

<!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Your Product">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="25.00">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

<!-- Specify checkout options. -->
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.yoursite.com/paymentsuccessful.hmtl">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.yoursite.com/paymentcancelled.hmtl">

<!-- Display the payment button. -->
<input type="image" name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif">
</form>
```

- **form action** - value is `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr`, removing "sandbox"
  means you are using the live PayPal website
- **business** - does not have to be a real email, text displayed at the upper-left portion of the PayPal checkout page
- **cmd** - `_xclick` means the button clicked was a Buy Now button
- **item_name** - name of your product
- **amount** - price of your product
- **currency_code** - read [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/) for supported values
- **no_note** - do not prompt buyers to include a note with their payments (0 - false, 1 - true)
- **no_shipping** - do not prompt buyers for a shipping address (0 - prompt but not required, 1 - do not prompt, 2 - prompt and require)
- **return** - URL to which PayPal redirects the buyer's browser after they complete their payment
- **cancel_return** - URL to which PayPal redirects the buyer's browser if they cancel checkout before completing their payment

**Output:**
[image]

**References:**
[Testing Classic API Calls](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/ug_sandbox/) (recommended reading)
[Single-Item Payments – Buy Now Buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/buynow_buttons/) (more options available)
[HTML Variables for Displaying PayPal Checkout Pages](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI0709B) (more options available)